# Optimizing queries with Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-debug-toolbar

I am using debug-toolbar to see the number of overall queries. The problem is that when I reload the page, I see different number of overall queries, given the same code and very short period of page reload intervals. I understand this is somehow related to caching.
The question is, is there any shortcut to make Django at least in the debug mode always run all the queries so that I can see the real impact of my changes in the code ?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't make sense for its contents. Maybe change it to something like "Preventing caching in ORM queries" for more clicks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed caching via the caching framework, then I'd recommend changing out your caching backend with the [`DummyCache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development).

From the docs:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```